# 3D multimodal medical image registration in python

Tags: python, image-processing, 3d, medical

I have searched and found a lot of 2D image registration images in Python, but those will not serve my need. I have several MRI and CT images all taken of the same patient over time and was wondering if anybody had sample Python code for performing a 3D rigid image registration for these medical images.

Answer (score 2):

```
you can use python in SimpleITK: 

https://itk.org/Wiki/SimpleITK/Tutorials/MICCAI2015

import SimpleITK as sitk

def save_combined_central_slice(fixed, moving, transform, file_name_prefix):
    global iteration_number 
    alpha = 0.7

    central_indexes = [i/2 for i in fixed.GetSize()]

    moving_transformed = sitk.Resample(moving, fixed, transform, 
                                       sitk.sitkLinear, 0.0, 
                                       moving_image.GetPixelIDValue())
    #extract the central slice in xy, xz, yz and alpha blend them                                   
    combined = [(1.0 - alpha)*fixed[:,:,central_indexes[2]] + \
                   alpha*moving_transformed[:,:,central_indexes[2]],
                  (1.0 - alpha)*fixed[:,central_indexes[1],:] + \
                  alpha*moving_transformed[:,central_indexes[1],:],
                  (1.0 - alpha)*fixed[central_indexes[0],:,:] + \
                  alpha*moving_transformed[central_indexes[0],:,:]]
    #resample the alpha blended images to be isotropic and rescale intensity
    #values so that they are in [0,255], this satisfies the requirements 
    #of the jpg format 
    combined_isotropic = []
    for img in combined:
        original_spacing = img.GetSpacing()
        original_size = img.GetSize()
        min_spacing = min(original_spacing)
        new_spacing = [min_spacing, min_spacing]
        new_size = [int(round(original_size[0]*(original_spacing[0]/min_spacing))), 
                    int(round(original_size[1]*(original_spacing[1]/min_spacing)))]
        resampled_img = sitk.Resample(img, new_size, sitk.Transform(), 
                                      sitk.sitkLinear, img.GetOrigin(),
                                      new_spacing, img.GetDirection(), 0.0, 
                                      img.GetPixelIDValue())        
        combined_isotropic.append(sitk.Cast(sitk.RescaleIntensity(resampled_img), 
                                            sitk.sitkUInt8))
    #tile the three images into one large image and save using the given file 
    #name prefix and the iteration number
    sitk.WriteImage(sitk.Tile(combined_isotropic, (1,3)), 
                    file_name_prefix+ format(iteration_number, '03d') + '.jpg')
    iteration_number+=1    



#read the images
fixed_image =  sitk.ReadImage("training_001_ct.mha", sitk.sitkFloat32)
moving_image = sitk.ReadImage("training_001_mr_T1.mha", sitk.sitkFloat32) 

#initial alignment of the two volumes
transform = sitk.CenteredTransformInitializer(fixed_image, 
                                              moving_image, 
                                              sitk.Euler3DTransform(), 
                                              sitk.CenteredTransformInitializerFilter.GEOMETRY)

#multi-resolution rigid registration using Mutual Information
registration_method = sitk.ImageRegistrationMethod()
registration_method.SetMetricAsMattesMutualInformation(numberOfHistogramBins=50)
registration_method.SetMetricSamplingStrategy(registration_method.RANDOM)
registration_method.SetMetricSamplingPercentage(0.01)
registration_method.SetInterpolator(sitk.sitkLinear)
registration_method.SetOptimizerAsGradientDescent(learningRate=1.0, 
                                                  numberOfIterations=100, 
                                                  convergenceMinimumValue=1e-6, 
                                                  convergenceWindowSize=10)
registration_method.SetOptimizerScalesFromPhysicalShift()
registration_method.SetShrinkFactorsPerLevel(shrinkFactors = [4,2,1])
registration_method.SetSmoothingSigmasPerLevel(smoothingSigmas=[2,1,0])
registration_method.SmoothingSigmasAreSpecifiedInPhysicalUnitsOn()
registration_method.SetInitialTransform(transform)

#add iteration callback, save central slice in xy, xz, yz planes
global iteration_number
iteration_number = 0
registration_method.AddCommand(sitk.sitkIterationEvent, 
                               lambda: save_combined_central_slice(fixed_image,
                                                                   moving_image,
                                                                   transform, 
                                                                   'output/iteration'))

registration_method.Execute(fixed_image, moving_image)

sitk.WriteTransform(transform, 'output/ct2mrT1.tfm')
```

Answer (score 1):

you might try lcreg, see https://pypi.org/project/lcreg. The pypi page provides a link to a tutorial and sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Try using MeVisLab to do this easily. Also, you could try FSL for more robust results.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout simpleItk or Itk library. They provide image registration algorithms out of box. For 3D registration all you need would be to pass the volumes for registration such as .mhd or .mha file and use 3D transforms.

You can refer to this link as well https://pyscience.wordpress.com/2014/11/02/multi-modal-image-segmentation-with-python-simpleitk/

Answer (score 0):

You can try for vtk; open the below link as have try. good luck
https://kitware.github.io/vtk-examples/site/Cxx/#working-with-structured-3d-data